# How to inspect consistency with two polygon which have to be the same position on QGIS 1.8.0

Tags: qgis

There are two polygons which have the common line and point in some parts.
These line and point should be the same position.

I want to know how to inspect these condition on QGIS 1.8.0.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **Extract Nodes** from Vector - Geometry Tools first. Then **Add Geometry columns** to the extracted points. Using the **Identify** tool, you can then check if the coordinates are really same and if not how much different they are.

Answer (score 0):

To check if the layers are identical, I enlarge the line thickness, and give them extreme different colours, like red and light green. Then I uncheck one after another to see if one ore both colours are visible, and exchange the layer order as well.

Other chance is to choose an edge point, and zoom with rectangle closer step by step. If an offset is visible, measure the difference in metrers. An offset of less than a millimeter should be ok.